# How to add a list item to SPO containing curly quotes using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am trying to load some data into a SharePoint Online list using PowerShell and the Graph API's batch endpoint (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch). I have the site and list IDs. The data has curly quotes in at least one of its fields. If I create a POST request with the following body in Graph Explorer (https://aka.ms/ge) and run it and everything works fine:

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "id": "755154",
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/",
            "body": {
                "fields": {
                    "Title": "Something “and” something"
                }
            },
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And I can verify that the data was inserted correctly; including the curly quotes:

[image]

Now if I try to do the same using the following PowerShell script, I get a Invalid Payloag error.

```
$tenant_id = "some-tenant-id-here"
$client_id = "a-valid-client-id" # from App registration
$client_secret = "the-client-secret" # from App registration

$authParams = @{
    TenantId     = $tenant_id
    ClientId     = $client_id
    ClientSecret = $client_secret | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
}

$auth = Get-MsalToken @authParams

$batch = @'
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "id": "755154",
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/",
      "body": {
        "fields": {
          "Title": "Something “else” here"
        }
      },
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }
  ]
}
'@

$headers = @{
  "Content-Type" = "application/json"
  "Authorization" = "Bearer $($auth.AccessToken)"
}

$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/`$batch"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Body $batch

$result
```

Here is an image of the error:

[image]

**Is it possible to replicate the behavior obtained with Graph Explorer from PowerShell?**

**[UPDATE 2/27/2023]**

@user2250152's suggestion results in the following and it is not the desired outcome:

[image]

**[UPDATE 2/28/2023]**

Here is a screenshot of the VS Code PowerShell terminal I'm using to run the script, also showing the version table:

[image]

Comment: Issue logged to msgraph-sdk-powershell too: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell/issues/1845

Answer (score 0):

I would use single quotes for json payload

```
$batch = @'
{
  'requests': [
    {
      'id': '755154',
      'method': 'POST',
      'url': '/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/',
      'body': {
        'fields': {
          'Title': 'Something “else” here'
        }
      },
      'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }
  ]
}
'@
```

Comment: It's interesting that that gets rid of the error, but it does not produce the desired result and it results in curly quotes being replaced by regular quotes.

Comment: @EduardoCMB That's really interesting. What tool do you use for PowerShell? Windows PowerShell ISE?

Comment: I use VS Code, which in turn uses a PowerShell terminal using the installed and configured version of PowerShell. I'll add an image of the terminal in VS Code showing the versions table.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a JSON string manually, it is better to generate it with tools that will do proper quoting and escaping automagically. In PowerShell, you can use `ConvertTo-Json` to create a JSON string from a custom object or a hash table. In your case, a hash table seems to be more convenient:

```
$batch = @{
  requests = @(
    [ordered]@{
      id = 755154
      method = 'POST'
      url = '/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/'
      body = @{
        fields = @{
          Title = 'Something “else” here'
        }
      }
      headers = @{
        'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
      }
    }
  )
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
```

Comment: It looks promising but it returns the error: `Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.`. If I remove curly quotes `'Something else here'` then the call succeeds

Comment: @stackprotector, as pointed out by user2250152, using this as payload to a call to Graph's batch endpoint it return a BadRequest error with message "Invalid batch payload format."

Comment: @EduardoCMB Did you try to escape the smart/fancy/curly quotes manually?

Comment: Yes, I did try to escape them. I get the same BadRequest response.